# Melhor tradução para a expressão inglesa "for the sake of"

Tags: expressões, tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

A expressão inglesa ***for the sake of*** parece ter várias traduções diferentes para o Português.

1. O [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/for+the+sake+of+clarity.html) indica que, por exemplo, ***for the sake of clarity*** pode ser traduzido de várias formas:

   - ***For the sake of clarity**, several Articles to which amendments need to be made should be republished in full* - **Por uma questão de clareza**, os artigos que tenham de ser alterados devem voltar a ser publicados na íntegra
   - ***For the sake of clarity** and transparency the Commission after consultation with the Belgian authorities, has taken Decision...* - **Por razões de clareza e transparência**, e após consulta das autoridades belgas, a Comissão adoptou a Decisão...
   - ***For the sake of clarity** it is noted that the Community industry has supplied information...* - **Por motivos de clareza**, importa assinalar que, na sua resposta ao questionário, a indústria comunitária forneceu informação...

   Entre outros.
2. Já [***for the sake of the profits***](http://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/search?source=auto&query=for+the+sake+of+the+profits) é traduzido como **em nome dos lucros** ou **para garantir os lucros** (entendi que varia conforme o contexto ou da posição da expressão na frase):

   - *...they again call on the workers to sacrifice themselves **for the sake of the profits** of the monopolies* - ...volta a pedir aos trabalhadores que se sacrifiquem **para garantir os lucros** dos monopólios
   - *The EU is sacrificing public health **for the sake of the profits** of European monopolies* - UE está a sacrificar a saúde pública **em nome dos lucros** dos monopólios europeus (PS: o [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/The%20EU%20is%20sacrificing%20public%20health%20for%20the%20sake%20of%20the%20profits%20of%20European%20monopolies) traduziu como ***em benefício dos lucros***)

   Claro que as opções acima (**"por uma questão de"**, **"por motivos de"**) também poderiam ser usadas, embora na minha opinião se "encaixem" melhor com **"clareza"** do que com **"lucros"**.

Pesquisando um pouco mais, encontro várias outras alternativas de tradução, dependendo da palavra que vem depois de ***for the sake of***. Alguns exemplos (todos encontrados no próprio linguee):

- ***for the sake of the world/children*** - **pelo bem do mundo/das crianças**
- *sacrifices had to be made **for the sake of entertainment*** - tenham sido sacrificados **em vista ao entretenimento** (essa eu achei bem estranha, eu usaria **em nome do entretenimento**)
- *we are determined to avoid compromising tomorrow **for the sake of today*** - estamos determinados em evitar comprometer o amanhã **por causa do hoje**

Tendo em vista tantas traduções diferentes, minha dúvida é: há uma tradução (ou mais de uma) que seja "a mais correta" para a expressão? Ou não há, e cada caso deve ser adaptado de acordo, dependendo mais do contexto e da palavra que a acompanha?

---

**PS:** estou desconsiderando a expressão ***For God's sake***, já que a tradução (pelo menos em **pt-BR**) é **Pelo amor de Deus**, mas claramente é um caso à parte, já que no meu entendimento ***sake*** não pode ser traduzido como **amor**.

Comment: "Pelo saco de"... haha! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na minha opinião, qualquer das traduções que apresentaste que começa pelas palavras *por* ou *pelo/pela* está correta.

#### A língua portuguesa e a palavra *sake* não têm uma raíz comum

O dicionário embutido no Google mostra a seguinte árvore etimológica para a palavra *sake* (imagem obtida com a pesquisa `define sake`):

[image: árvore etimológica da palavra inglesa "sake"]

Como se pode ver, a palavra *sake* não tem origem comum com a língua portuguesa.

#### O que se pretende indicar é que uma das orações na frase tem um objetivo a alcançar

O dicionário no Google dá também a seguinte explicação quanto à utilização do substantivo *sake*:

> *used to indicate something that is done as an end in itself rather than to achieve some other purpose*

Assim, dá para tentar criar uma tradução com base nesta definição. As palavras chave são *done as an end in itself* e *achieve*. Isto é, *sake* denota um objetivo que se pretende alcançar.

Ao nível sintático o fragmento *for the sake of*  apresenta o motivo/propósito de uma outra oração que se encontra na frase. Pode-se dizer que a relação das orações é do tipo objetivo-ação.

#### Parece estar bem traduzido quando começa por "por"/"pelo"/"pela"

As traduções encontradas pelo *linguee* para o teu exemplo 1 estão corretas:

- ***For the sake of clarity*** -> Por uma questão de clareza
- ***For the sake of clarity and transparency*** -> Por razões de clareza e transparência
- ***For the sake of clarity*** -> Por motivos de clareza

No teu exemplo 2, há qualquer coisa estranha nas traduções:

- ***for the sake of the profits*** -> ✤em nome dos lucros
- ***for the sake of the profits*** -> ✤em benefício dos lucros

*Em nome [de]* aponta mais para uma **causa** do que para um objetivo a alcançar. O mesmo pode ser dito para o segundo caso.

- ***for the sake of the profits*** -> ✤para garantir os lucros

Na minha opinião, esta tradução está errada. *Garantir* é um verbo. O fragmento *for the sake of the profits* não tem qualquer verbo.

Parece-me que qualquer das traduções que indicaste que comecem pela palavra "por" estão corretas.

Answer (score 7):

Em português existe uma belíssima expressão, **por mor de**, cuja origem é *<sup>por</sup>/<sub>pelo</sub> amor de*.

O facto de vir de *amor* não é problema.  É mesmo um modismo hoje cujo significado original não perdura mas tem sentido.  Coisa parecida acontece com a expressão inglesa: *sake* no inglês antigo significava *causa/processo jurídico/crime*.  Mas em ambas as línguas, agora, significam quer *por causa de* quer *com motivo de*.

Answer (score 1):

pode ser traduzido como "em nome de" ou "a favor de", como em "a favor dos lucros". O mais importante é lembrar que muitas vezes não vai existir tradução única (uma única forma) ou ainda uma tradução literal. Toda tradução leva em consideração aspectos culturais e de significado, portanto uma mesma expressão pode ser traduzida de maneiras diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as outras respostas, um uso que tenho visto muito é:

- For the sake of example -> **a título de** exemplo

Mais uma:

- Reply just for the sake of it -> responder **só por** responder

Answer (score 0):

Collins Dictionary:

**sake
[seɪk]
NOUN
**for the sake of** **por (causa de) ⧫ em consideração a**

for sb's/sth's sake = pelo bem de alguém/algo

for my sake = por mim

arguing for arguing's sake = brigar por brigar

for the sake of argument = por exemplo

for heaven's sake! = pelo amor de Deus!**

[English>Portuguese Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-portuguese/sake)